# How do I group by a variable and list by a random order in data.table?

Tags: r, permutation, data.table, sample

I have a variable that I want to group by. That is easy. However, I want the resultant table to list its rows by random order. What I actually want to do is a little more complicated. But allow me to show you a simplified version.

```
mydf = data.table(
   x = rep(1:4, each = 5),
   y = rep(c('A', 'B','c','D', 'E'), times = 2),
   v = rpois(20, 30)
)

mydf[,list(sum(x),sum(v)), by=y]
mydf[,list(sum(x),sum(v)), by=list(y=sample(y))]

#to list all the raw data in order of y


mydf[,list(x,v), by=y]
mydf[,list(x,v), by=list(y=sample(y))]
```

If you look at the resultant outputs you will notice that the y is indeed in random order but it has become unhinged from the data that was in the rows with it.

What can I do?

Comment: Why not return the `data.table` normally and then do your random ordering?

Comment: @Justin, random ordering the returned table would work for the table that shows the sums but it would not work for the next set where one wants to list the raw data but where one still wants it listed by group of y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do the operation and then order randomly:

```
mydf[,list(x,v),by=y][sample(seq_len(nrow(mydf)),replace=FALSE)]
```

EDIT: Random reordering, after grouping:

```
mydf[,list(sum(x),sum(v)), by=y][sample(seq_len(length(y)),replace=FALSE)]
```

You can do something like this to group and random order before grouping, and it looks like it does preserve the changed order:

```
mydf[order(setNames(sample(unique(y)),unique(y))[y])]
mydf[order(setNames(sample(unique(y)),unique(y))[y]),list(sum(x),sum(v)),by=y]

#perhaps more readable:
mydf[{z <- unique(y); order(setNames(sample(z),z)[y])}]
mydf[{z <- unique(y); order(setNames(sample(z),z)[y])},list(sum(x),sum(v)),by=y]
```

This is more transparent by adding a column first before ordering.

```
mydf[,new.y := setNames(sample(unique(y)),unique(y))[y]][order(new.y)]
```

Breaking it down:

```
##a random ordering of the elements of y 
##(set.seed is used here to get consistent results)
set.seed(1); mydf[,{z <- unique(y);sample(z)}]
# [1] "B" "E" "D" "c" "A"
##assigning names to the elements of y
##creating a 1-1 bijective function between the elements of y
set.seed(1); mydf[,{z <- unique(y);setNames(sample(z),z)}]
#  A   B   c   D   E 
#"B" "E" "D" "c" "A" 
##subsetting by y puts y through the map
##in effect every element of y is posing as an element of y, picked at random
##notice that the names (top row) are the original y
##the values (bottom row) are the mapped-to values
#  A   B   c   D   E   A   B   c   D   E   A   B   c   D   E   A   B   c   D   E 
#"B" "E" "D" "c" "A" "B" "E" "D" "c" "A" "B" "E" "D" "c" "A" "B" "E" "D" "c" "A"
##ordering by this now orders by the mapped-to values
set.seed(1); mydf[{z <- unique(y);order(setNames(sample(z),z)[y])}]
```

**EDIT:** Incorporating Arun's suggestion in the comments to use `setattr` to set the names:

```
mydf[{z <- unique(y); order(setattr(sample(z),'names',z)[y])}]
mydf[{z <- unique(y); order(setattr(sample(z),'names',z)[y])},list(sum(x),sum(v)),by=y]
```

Comment: That code simply returns the original raw data in random order. However, I want all rows of a particular y (randomly ordered) to be listed together.

Comment: It works but I barely understand what you did. What is `setNames` doing? It seems to be randomly assigning each value of y with a different value of y. Then it is creating a permutation of that assigning against Y and feeding that vector of numbers to be the i value in X[i]

Comment: @BlueMagister, If you're using `data.table`, then you should be using `setnames` (not `setNames`.

Comment: @Arun `setnames` is for `data.table`, not ordinary vectors.

Comment: @Farrel I broke it down into pieces and added that to my answer. You are correct that it re-maps values of y. It then orders by the new mapping but doesn't actually change any values.

Comment: @Arun Indeed I had read setNames{stats} help file. In fact it was one of the first things I did. "This is a convenience function that sets the names on an object and returns the object.", did not help me very much. Maybe it is because I am not a "real" programer. Wish I was!

Comment: @BlueMagister, not quite sure what you mean. What I meant was, for ex, the last line (or any other line where you've `setNames` inside a `DT`. `set.seed(1); mydf[{z <- unique(y); order(setattr(sample(z), 'names', z)[y])}]`. This does it by reference, no copies are being made. `setNames` copies the object. Try this: `x <- sample(10); tracemem(x); setattr(x, 'names', letters[1:10]); tracemem(x)`. Now, replace `setattr` with `setNames(x, letters[1:10])` and watch it make a copy.

Comment: @Farrel, the way I'd do is this: `x <- sample(10); setNames(x, letters[1:10])`. What does it output? What has changed from `x` in the first assignment? I see that there are names being assigned to each element of the vector. Ah wait, now the documentation makes sense! It's just that much. It sets names to names on an object and returns that named object.

Comment: @Arun Oh, okay. Understood. I tried using `setnames` but it ran into an error: `x is not a data.table or data.frame`. I will change names via `setattr` next time.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for...?

```
mydf[,.SD[sample(.N)],by=y]
```

Inspired by @BlueMagister's second solution, here's the randomize-first way:

```
mydf[sample(nrow(mydf)),.SD,by=y]
```

Here, use `keyby` instead of `by` if you want the groups to appear in alphabetical order.